# onClick with Bootstrap, JavaScript and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

What I'm trying to do is, SELECT * customers from a database, insert them into a dropdown menu, and when I choose a customer from that particular dropdown menu, his other data is outputted, like mobile number and email.

This is my code:

- PS. Sorry about all the "echo", I had it crash on me a couple of times, I'm new to PHP

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <?php $servername="localhost" ; $username="admin_default" ; $password="_" ; $dbname="admin_default" ; // Create connection $conn=n ew mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); ?>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Choose a customer</h2>
      <hr/>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">

        <?php // Check connection if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } echo "Connected successfully
        <br>"; $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers"; $result = $conn->query($sql); if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // output data of each row while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo "
        <option onclick='loadData(";
        echo $row[' id '];
        echo ");'>"; echo $row['company_name']; echo "</option>"; } } else { echo '
        <option>No customers found</option>'; } $conn->close(); ?>

      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadData(d) {
      console.log(d);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query=Select * from customers  
...  
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){  
   echo "<option value="'.$row['data_id'].'">".$row['data']."</option>";
}
```

And your js

```
dropdown.on(change, function(){
        Get the value of the dropdown and use it for your query to display data.
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the javascript code makes no sense, what do you refer to by "dropdown" ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought it was a select tag in html. But it just the same scenario. You just need to change the <option> to an element which you refer the value to be stored. Usually you use a <li> tag.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap and as you can notice, I don't think it'll work the same?

Comment: echo <li id=$data_id>$data</li>. It looks like that and if youre using jquery. You can use like this in clicking. $("li").click(function(){ alert(this.id) });

Comment: Your scenario is: Get the record from the database and then display it from a dropdown menu. Then if dropdown menu is clicked, then display some data based on the clicked menu.

Comment: $("option").click(function(){ alert(this.title) });

Comment: Dont use "onclick" in an option tag. Use onchange in the select tag

Comment: $("#id_of_the_select_tag").on('change', function(){ alert($(this).val()); });